# Making an element expand to the width of its contents (when the contents are wider than the viewport)

Tags: css

After about 15 years writing CSS, I'm still discovering things I don't understand...

Below is a simple page with an `h1` element that is 2000px wide. As expected, this causes the page to have a horizontal scrollbar.

But the problem is, the parent `div.wrapper` does not expand to the width of its contents – its yellow background only extends as far as the width of the viewport. (Run the below snippet and scroll horizontally to see the problem.)

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.wrapper { background: yellow; }

h1 {
  width: 2000px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Hello</h1>

      <p>More content</p>
    </div>
    
    <p>More content outside wrapper</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the weird thing: Try adding `body { position: absolute }` to the above CSS and it fixes it. The `div.wrapper` now extends to the width of its contents – the yellow goes all the way to the right of the document.

Questions:

1. **Why** does setting `body { position: absolute }` fix the problem?
2. Are there any better (more intuitive) ways to fix the problem?

Constraints: I do not always know the width of the inner contents, I just want the wrapper to always extend so its background color goes all the way to the right of the contents.

Comment: `position:absolute` or `display:table` for wrapper also will fix the issue.

Comment: .wrapper is block element and by default it's 100% width of parent .. make it inline-block and see the magic

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai position absolute on the wrapper breaks the layout, causing the second p element to be hidden.

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks, inline-block works, but the downside of that is it means I can't use the wrapper's `display` property for any other purpose (for example if I want to set it to `display: flex` so I can make its children flexible).

Comment: you can, there is also `inline-flex` that does the same magic ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif nice. If you could post that as an answer, with some explanation of how the inline magic works, I will give you some internet points

Comment: i also added explanation about why the absolute position fix your issue ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with this:

> But the problem is, the parent **div.wrapper** does **not expand** to the
>   **width** of its contents – its yellow background only extends as far as
>   the width of the viewport.

By default a div is a block element and a block element takes up the **whole width** of it's parent container so your wrapper in this case has the width of the body which is the width of the screen. In addition to this we are facing an **overflow** as the child content width is bigger than the parent width and by default:

> Content is not clipped and may be rendered outside the padding box<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)</sup>

This explain why the background doesn't cover the `h1` as this one is **rendred outside**.

To change this behavior we have two solutions:

1. We change the behavior of [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) by specifing a value different from `visible` (the default one). By doing this you will also notice some changes to margin because you are also facing a **margin collapsing** (margin of `h1` and `p` are collpasing with the margin of `div.wrapper`).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background: yellow;
  margin:10px 0;
}

h1 {
  width: 2000px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="overflow: auto;">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>More content</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>More content</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper" style="overflow: scroll;">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>More content</p>
</div>
<p>More content outside wrapper</p>
```

2. We change the display property of the element to something else than block. We can for example use `inline-block` or `inline-flex` and in this case the wrapper will fit the content of its element and he will **overflow** the body

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
  width: 2000px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>More content</p>
</div>
<p>More content outside wrapper</p>
```

---

Concerning this:

> Why does setting body { position: absolute } fix the problem?

We all know what `position:absolute` means but the intresting part is this one:

> Most of the time, absolutely positioned elements that have height and
>   width **set to auto** are sized so **as to fit their contents**. However,
>   non-replaced, absolutely positioned elements can be made to fill the
>   available vertical space by specifying both top and bottom and leaving
>   height unspecified (that is, auto). They can likewise be made to fill
>   the available horizontal space by specifying both left and right and
>   leaving width as auto. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told the div how to handle the overflow caused by the width of the inner element. Add `overflow: auto`.

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.wrapper { background: yellow; overflow: auto; }

h1 {
  width: 2000px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Hello</h1>

      <p>More content</p>
    </div>
    
    <p>More content outside wrapper</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I do not believe that there is an obvious reason why adding `position: absolute` to the body *fixes* this. It does take body out of the document flow, but body is the container for all the content. So I would describe it as a quirk.

We could describe body as being the initial constraint for the width of the content, the .wrapper. Being absolute removes this constraint. Actually, it likely remove the width constraint for any further elements on the page, so they will probably all expand to contain any inner content.

Comment: so by default body take 100% width because it's a block element but after adding position:absolute, this behavior disappear

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I run your snippet it has a horizontal scrollbar on the wrapper div, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can use `width: fit-content;`

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) describes it as;

> **fit-content**
>   The larger of:
>
> - the intrinsic minimum width
> - the smaller of the intrinsic preferred width and the available width

It works as expected; the containing element expands. But, as usual, IE lags behind and doesn't support it...

**EDIT** To be clear; this specification is still in [Working Draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-box-3/#width-and-height) status, and as such should not be used in production environments (except if you don't care about Internet Explorer).

Comment: Check [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=fit-content) for support of fit-content if this is the desired solution.

Comment: This shouldn't be downvoted, it just needs to mention that it's still a working draft and isn't widely supported yet.

Comment: Yeah I said that already... btw; of all major browsers only IE doesn't support it, so we're almost there